# how can i wait in cypress until recieve my response from my server

Tags: react-redux, cypress, cypress-intercept

I have a call to my server (is a call that go to ibm watson) make somethings, and return me a 200 response if all is OK.

This call i bigger than 5000ms that cypress can wait.
I need to wait until the server return the response, and then, i know that a popup will appear in my react app.

this is my call from my backend to watson:

```js
const launchWatsonTest = (watsonData) => {     
  const data = {
    withCredentials: true,
    mode: 'cors',
     headers: {
      'x-access-token': watsonData.token,      
    }, 
    params: {
      topicId: watsonData.corpusNameId,
      workspaceId: watsonData.corpusArea
    }
  };      
  return clienteAxios.post(`test-watson`, watsonData, data);  
};
```

How can i wait before to continue with the test?

i have this test with cypress:

```js
  describe("E2E CognitiveTool", function() {
    it("should crear respuesta simple sin problemas", function() {
      cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");
      cy.contains('[data-cy="topicName"]', 'CA2');   
      cy.get('[data-cy="accederResponsesCA2"]').click();
      cy.get('[data-cy="crearResponse"]').should('exist')
        .click();
      cy.get('input[name="description"]')
        .type('Simple Cypres Response');      
      cy.get('[name="typeResponse"]').first().check({force:true});
      cy.get('[name="lateral_W"]').first().check({force:true});
      cy.get('[name="rolViews"]').first().check({force:true});
      cy.get('[name="workLoadLevel"]').first().check({force:true});
      cy.get('[data-cy="continuar"]').click();
      cy.get('input[id=0]')
        .type('hola');
      cy.get('input[id=1]')
        .type('adios');
      cy.get('input[id=2]')
        .type('cypress');
      cy.get('input[id=3]')
        .type('jest');
      cy.get('input[id=4]')
        .type('testing');
      cy.get('input[id=5]')
        .type('automatico');     
      cy.get('[data-cy="testing"]').should('exist')
        .click({force: true});
      cy.waitUntil(()=>cy.intercept({method: 'POST', url:'**/test-watson'}).as('testData'), { // here is when i need to wait and then continue
        timeout: 40000,
      });      
      cy.wait('@testData');
      cy.window()
        .its('open')
        .should('exist')
        .get('[data-cy="continuar]').click();

      
    });
});
```

I recieve this in command log in cypress console:

[image]

i did try with wait, with waitUntil, with getrequest() (that not works because i don't know how configure the headers error.....)

Some help for me.
Thanks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `waitUntil()` is not necessary, Cypress intercept with a `cy.wait()` is all you need.

Look at [wait - options](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Arguments)

> **responseTimeout** - Overrides the global responseTimeout for this request.

But the pattern you have used is wrong. The `cy.intercept()` goes *before* the action the triggers the `POST`.

```js
// start listening
cy.intercept({method: 'POST', url:'**/test-watson'}).as('testData');

// fill form
...
// click submit and fire the POST call
cy.get('[data-cy="testing"]').click()

// wait for intercept
cy.wait('@testData', {responseTimeout: 10_000})
```